# Replace values in column, space delimited file in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a file that looks like:

```
2067 24311 <hkxhk> {00}
2069 17219 <hkxhk> {00}
2071 20931 <hkxhk> {00}
2073 5557  <hkxhk> {00}
2075 2127  <hkxhk> {00}
2077 20947 <hkxhk> {00}
2081 18088 <hkxhk> {00}
```

I want to replace the first column value so that it looks like

```
5 24311 <hkxhk> {00}
5 17219 <hkxhk> {00}
5 20931 <hkxhk> {00}
5 5557  <hkxhk> {00}
5 2127  <hkxhk> {00}
5 20947 <hkxhk> {00}
5 18088 <hkxhk> {00}
```

Where the first space delimited column has been replaced by a new value, in this case 5.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using search and replace:

```
:%s/^\S*/5/
```

`%s` – search throughout the file,
`^` – start of line,
`\S` – any non-space char,
`\S*` – any number of any non-space chars,
`5` – your new value.

#### Using macros:

```
qq0cw5<Esc>q
:%norm! @q
```

`qq` – start recording a macros named `q`,
`0` – place cursor at the beginning of a line,
`cw5` – replace (**c**hange) one **w**ord with `5`, 
`<Esc>` – return to normal mode, 
`q` – end recording the macros;

`%norm!` – apply normal-mode command to every line of file,
 `@q` – execute macros `q` (a normal-mode command).

#### Using visual selection *assuming that first column has constant width (4 chars)*:

```
gg0<C-v>G3lc5<Esc>
```

`gg0` – put cursor at the beginning of the file,
`<C-v>` – start block selection mode,
`G` – go to the last line so selecting one-char-width column (H×1 block),
`3l` – go three chars left so selecting H×4 block,
`c5<Esc>` – replace selection in every line with `5` and return to normal mode.

#### Conclusion

Your problem is so elementary that search-and-replace approach turned out to be the simplest here while in general case recording a macros is much more convenient than inventing a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, on Mac OSX, or in MINGw, or any system that has the `column` tool (and chances are very high if you're using Vim), then you can use it to columnate your file:

- `column` is a [Linux tool to columnate lists](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html)
- `-t` Count the number of columns that the file has.
- `-s` When counting columns, interpret this as the current column separator.
- `-o` When modifying the file, use this as the new column separator.

You can execute the `command` tool directly from the prompt. For example:

```
column my-file.txt -t -s "|" -o " | " > my-file-columnated.txt
```

Or you can execute it from Vim in command mode:

- `:%!column -t -s "|" -o " | "`
- `:` is the standard to execute a command.
- `%` affects the whole file content. If you omit it, you will perform the operation on selected lines only. If no selected lines, then you will affect your current line only.
- `!` executes an external tool.

And, if your column separator is just a space, like in the case of the original poster, then you're in luck because the default separator used by `column` is precisely the space:

```
:%!column -t
```